# Use method parameters names when generating WSDL from Java using wsgen and maven?

Tags: java, web-services, maven-2, wsgen

I'm generating a WSDL from a Java class using the `@WebService` annotation and running `wsgen`, triggered by a Maven build target.

The problem I have is the generated WSDL defines the parameters for the web service operations as `arg0, ar1, arg2`, etc instead of using the parameter names from the code.  These names are not helpful to clients of the service attempting to figure out what needs to be passed in.

Is there a way to tell wsgen to grab and use the parameter names from the method - either by placing an annotation on the method or a parameter sent to wsgen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `@WebParam` annotation.

```
@WebMethod
public void thisMethodHasAWebParam(@WebParam(name="param1") String arg1) {
}
```

Comment: I knew there had to be an easy way to do this.  Thanks so much!

Comment: That works. But isn't this horribly redundant? I know that method signatures in byte code do not preserve the parameter names, but cannot the tool also look at the source code?

Comment: How it can look into source code, as it uses WSDL file URL when generating code. And WSDL file is generated at runtime.